# CORS Error after deploying react app to netlify with Node/Express backend and MySQL in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, cors, response-headers

Before I deploy, the app performed fine on localhost. But since I deployed my frontend (react) to Netlify and backend(node/express + mysql) to Heroku, all requests sent from the frontend started to get blocked by CORS policy, with the error message:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxx.herokuapp.com/login' from origin 'https://xxx.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://xxx.app/' that is not equal to the supplied origin."

Most importantly, the value of my Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is **literally the same** as the origin stated.

Originally, I've tried to use a wildcard ("*"), but it seems that due to the withCredential problem, the system just can't allow that kind of vague statement.
I've also seen many people using Netlify.toml to tackle some configuration problems, but seems ineffective for me.

Is it the header's problem? If not, then what is the problem?

I really want to know what I should do to solve this error...

The console window of the app deployed:
[Cors Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLDrA.png)

My index.js in the server folder:

```js
const express = require('express')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const cors = require('cors')
const session = require('express-session')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const port = 3010

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors({
  origin: ["https://xxx.app/"], // the link of my front-end app on Netlify
  methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  credentials: true
}))

app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
app.use(
  session({
    key: "userId",
    secret: "subscribe",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      expires: 60 * 60 * 24
    },
  })
)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://xxx.netlify.app/"); // the link of my front-end app on Netlify
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
  next();
});

const db = mysql.createPool({
  // create an instance of the connection to the mysql database
  host: 'xxx.cleardb.net', // specify host name
  user: 'xxx', // specify user name
  password: 'xxx', // specify password
  database: 'heroku_xxx', // specify database name
})

...

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.user) {
    res.send({
      isLoggedIn: true,
      user: req.session.user
    })
  } else {
    res.send({
      isLoggedIn: false
    })
  }
})

...

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => {
  console.log('Successfully Running server at ' + port + '.')
});
```

My Frontend:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import '../App.css'
import './HeroSection.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Axios from 'axios'

function HeroSection() {
  Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
  let username = "";
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  
  ...
  
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('https://xxx.herokuapp.com/login').then((response) => {
      if (response.data.isLoggedIn) {
        username = response.data.user[0].username;
      }
      setIsLoggedIn(response.data.isLoggedIn)
      Axios.post('https://xxx.herokuapp.com/getLang', {
        username: username,
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      Axios.post('https://xxx.herokuapp.com/getStatus', {
        username: username,
      }).then(response => {
        setName(response.data[0].firstname + " " + response.data[0].lastname);
        setLoading(false);
      })
    })
  }, [])

  if (!isLoggedIn || isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>
      ...
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
      ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default HeroSection
```

By the way, I use ClearDB MySQL on Heroku and MySQL WorkBench for the database, which all works fine.

Comment: As far as I know the CORS origin should not end with a trailing slash, so try removing it.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You could debug by doing something like:

```
const allowList = ["https://yyy.app/"];

// Your origin prop in cors({})
origin: function (origin, callback) {
    // Log and check yourself if the origin actually matches what you've defined in the allowList array
    console.log(origin);

    if (allowList.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
```